# How can I apply a style to a parent of a specific child

Tags: jquery, css

I've created a menu where if the user clicks on one of the side menu items then the side menu and the side menu children are all displayed, but the problem I have is that all my menu items are bold instead of the selected child and it's parent.

I hope I explained this clearly,

My HTML

```
<div id="second-menu" class="collapse navbar-collapse menu_two">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav inside-nav">
        <li class="sub_menu">   
            <a href="#">Section 1</a>
            <ul class="sidenav_wrapper">
                <li class="sidenav_item sidenavlast">
                    <a href="#">Section 2</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="sub_menu">
            <a href="#">Section 3</a>
            <ul class="sidenav_wrapper">
                <li class="sidenav_item">
                    <a href="#">Section 4</a>
                </li>
                <li class="sidenav_active">
                    <a href="#">Section 5</a>
                </li>
                <li class="sidenav_item">   
                    <a href="#">Section 6</a>
                </li>
                <li class="sidenav_item sidenavlast">
                    <a href="#">Section 7</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="sub_menu">
            <a href="#">Section 8</a>
            <ul class="sidenav_wrapper">
                <li class="sidenav_item">
                    <a href="#">Section 9</a>
                </li>
                <li class="sidenav_item">
                    <a href="#">Section 10</a>
                </li>
                <li class="sidenav_item sidenavlast">
                    <a href="#">Section 11</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My JS

```
    $('ul.navbar-nav li').hover(

    function () {
        $(this).find('.sidenav_wrapper:first').css('display', 'block');
    },

    function () {
        $(this).find('.sidenav_wrapper:first').css('display', 'none');
    });


    $(".sidenav_active").parent().css({
        "display": "block"
    });


    if ($('.sidenav_active').length > 0) {
        $('.sidenav_wrapper').parent().find('a').css({
            "font-weight": "700"
        });
    }
```

My CSS

```
.menu_two {
    border-left: 16px solid #dfdfdf;
    padding-left: 0;
}
.sidenav_wrapper {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #e7ecf5;
    border-left: 6px solid #8fb8e6;
    display: none;
    padding: 0;
}

.active_sub_menu a{
    font-weight: 700;
}

.active_sub_menu .sidenav_wrapper{
        display: block;
    }

.sidenav_active a{
        font-weight: 700;
    }
```

My jsfiddle: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8pugw4n0/)

Comment: Could it be the `font-weight` you have applied?

Comment: WHat did you expect `font-weight:700` to do? It is equivalent to `bold`

Comment: That is because you are adding `"font-weight": "700"` to every link in your `if(..)`

Comment: @Paulie_D - My jquery has set all the sub_menu links to bold instead of the parent that I asked for

Comment: @Shaunak D - Then how would I go about doing what I need to do?

Comment: I have no idea why this question with short code sample and jsfiddle link deserves so many downvotes.  Looks like a clear question with definitive answers.  +1 from me.

Comment: Please do not give negative votes -9 and so on , comment it the reason. OP could delete the question. This is simple question I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is

```
$('ul.navbar-nav li').hover(function () {
    $(this).find('.sidenav_wrapper:first').css('display', 'block');
}, function () {
    $(this).find('.sidenav_wrapper:first').css('display', 'none');
});

$(".sidenav_active").parent().css({
    "display": "block"
});

$('.sidenav_active').closest('.sub_menu').find('a').css({
    "font-weight": "700"
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/r78xskcr/)

Answer (score 1):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8pugw4n0/2/)

```
font-weight: 700; is in your js
```

[Read about font-weight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight)

As per comment:

[Demo2](http://jsfiddle.net/8pugw4n0/8/) Do you mean this?

You can set `font-weight` while you hover it and remove that while you stop hovering.

Comment: I also need the parent to be bold. In this case it would be Section 3

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by your js:

```
if ($('.sidenav_active').length > 0) {
    $('.sidenav_wrapper').parent().find('a').css({
        "font-weight": "700"
    });
```

which is saying;

*if you have a side_active class in your css, select all sub_wrapper elements and select all child a elements, giving them a font-weight of 700.*

I can't advise as to what this code is looking to do, but removing it 'fixes' your issue.

If you're looking to have this as an 'active' choice instead, you may want to look into something like addClass and removeClass functions.

Comment: I'm trying to get the parent to be bold as well as the class sidenav_active. I've already got sidenav_active bold in my css. I just can't get the parent to be bold.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of following block of code:

```
if ($('.sidenav_active').length > 0) {
    $('.sidenav_wrapper').parent().find('a').css({
        "font-weight": "700"
    });
}
```

If i correctly understand your intent, the code should be changed to following:

```
$('.sidenav_active').closest('.sub_menu').children('a').css({
    "font-weight": "700"
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hazzik/hzyp66br/

Or using combination of [`:has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has/) and `>` selectors:

```
$('.sub_menu:has(.sidenav_active) > a').css({
    "font-weight": "700"
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hazzik/hzyp66br/1/

Comment: I'm trying to get the parent to be bold as well as the class sidenav_active. I've already got sidenav_active bold in my css. I just can't get the parent to be bold.